# Telegram webhook: Is ssl mandatory?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to know if SSL certificate and URL starting with `https://` is mandatory for webhook of a Telegram bot?
As it noticed in https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook it seems it is necessary, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely necessary. You could use self-signed certificate.

Comment: Why are you not sure if it is necessary? The documentation says it is, what makes you believe otherwise?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I hoped that may be it works without SSL/HTTPS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Telegram [Bot documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests) says:

All queries to the Telegram Bot API must be served over HTTPS and need to be presented in this form.

> - You need a valid SSL certificate for webhooks to work.
> - To use a self-signed certificate, you need to upload your public key certificate - using the certificate parameter in setWebhook. Please
>     upload as InputFile, - sending a String will not work.
> - Ports currently supported for Webhooks: 443, 80, 88, 8443.
> - Wildcard certificates may not be supported.
> - Redirects are not supported.
> - CN must exactly match your domain.

Setting up SSL is not hard  and there or completely free ways too(like free valid SSL certs or self-sign methods)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without ssl. Very useful solution in case using localhost for development. Just install Telegram Bot Api server, and you can use http links for localhost for webhooks. There are code and install instructions: https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api
You should use http://localhost:8081/ instead of default api url, and should start server with a --local option - like this: `/usr/local/bin/telegram-bot-api --local -v 3 --username leonid --groupname www-data`